# How can I get localStorage key name that based on what I input in form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a blog thumbnail and blog content with blog content input.

I have blog input form and the thumbnail on the same page, here's the code for the page:

```js
let blogs = []



let month = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sept",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
]

function addBlog(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    let inputName = document.getElementById("inputProjectName").value
    let inputContent = document.getElementById("inputDescription").value
    let inputImage = document.getElementById("inputImage").files[0]

    const projectDate = {

        startDate: document.getElementById("inputStartDate").value,
        endDate: document.getElementById("inputEndDate").value
    }

    inputImage = URL.createObjectURL(inputImage)

    let cardIcons = {
        html: document.querySelector('input[name="checkHtml"]').checked,
        css: document.querySelector('input[name="checkCss"]').checked,
        nodeJs: document.querySelector('input[name="checkNode"]').checked,
        reactJs: document.querySelector('input[name="checkReact"]').checked
    }

    let blog = {
        title: inputName,
        date: projectDate,
        content: inputContent,
        icons: cardIcons,
        image: inputImage
    }

    blogs.push(blog)

    console.table(blogs)

    renderCard()
}

function renderCard() {

    let containerBlog = document.getElementById("contents")
    containerBlog.innerHTML = '';

    const objectBlogString = JSON.stringify(blogs);

    for (let i = 0; i < blogs.length; i++) {

        localStorage.setItem(`${blogs[i].title}`, objectBlogString);

        containerBlog.innerHTML += `
        <div id="contents" class="mp-card">
            <!--MPC = My Project Card-->
            <div class="mpc-img">
                <img src="${blogs[i].image}" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="mpc-title">
            <a href="blog-detail.html" onclick="renderBlog(event)" id='${blogs[i].title} action="blog-detail.html"'>
                <p>${blogs[i].title}</p>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mpc-duration">
                <small>Durasi: 1 Bulan</small>
            </div>
            <div class="mpc-content">
                ${blogs[i].content}
            </div>
            <div class="mpc-icons">
                ${(blogs[i].icons.html === true) ? '<i class="fa-brands fa-html5"></i>' : ''}
                ${(blogs[i].icons.css === true) ? '<i class="fa-brands fa-css3-alt"></i>' : ''}
                ${(blogs[i].icons.nodeJs === true) ? '<i class="fa-brands fa-node-js"></i>' : ''}
                ${(blogs[i].icons.reactJs === true) ? '<i class="fa-brands fa-react"></i>' : ''}  
            </div>
            <div class="mpc-mod">
                <button>Edit</button>
                <button>Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        `
    }
}

function renderBlog(event) {

    let keyName;

    if (event) {

        keyName = event.path[1].id;

        const myProjectBody = document.getElementById('myProjectBody');

        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyName))

        myProjectBody.innerHTML = '';

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


            myProjectBody.innerHTML += `
            <div id="blog-detail">
        <!--BD = Blog Detail-->
        <div class="bd-title">
            <p>${data[i].title}</p>
        </div>
        <!--IDC = Image, Duration, Categories-->
        <div class="bd-idc">
            <div class="idc-left">
                <img src="${data[i].image}" alt="Blog Image">
            </div>
            <div class="idc-right">
                <p>Duration</p>
                <div class="bd-duration">
                    <div style="padding-left: 2px;">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-days"></i>
                        <p>1 Jan 2022 - 1 Aug 2022</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-clock"></i>
                        <p>8 Month</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bd-tech">
                    <p>Technologies</p>
                    <div class="tech-body">
                    ${(data[i].icons.html === true) ? '<div class="tech-html"><i class="fa-brands fa-html5"></i><p>HTML</p></div>' : ''}
                    ${(data[i].icons.css === true) ? '<div class="tech-css"><i class="fa-brands fa-css3-alt"></i><p>CSS</p></div>' : ''}
                    ${(data[i].icons.nodeJs === true) ? '<div class="tech-node"><i class="fa-brands fa-node-js"></i><p>nodeJs</p></div>' : ''}
                    ${(data[i].icons.reactJs === true) ? '<div class="tech-react"><i class="fa-brands fa-react"></i><p>reactJs</p></div>' : ''}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bd-content">
            <p>
                ${data[i].content}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
            `
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-left">
            <a href="/"><img src="assets/logo.png" alt=""></a>

            <ol>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="myproject.html">My Project</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-right">
            <a href="contact.html">Contact me</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--xNAVBARx-->

    <div id="myProjectBody">
        <!--MPI = My Project Input-->
        <div class="mpi-title">
            <p>ADD BLOG</p>
        </div>
        <!--Form-->
        <div class="mpi-form-container">
            <div class="mpi-form">
                <!--MP = My Project Input-->
                <form onsubmit="addBlog(event)" action="blog-detail.html">
                    <div class="mpi-name">
                        <label for="inputProjectName">Project Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="inputProjectName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mpi-date">
                        <div class="date-start">
                            <label for="inputStartDate">Start Date</label>
                            <input type="date" id="inputStartDate">
                        </div>
                        <div class="date-end">
                            <label for="inputEndDate">End Date</label>
                            <input type="date" id="inputEndDate">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mpi-desc">
                        <label for="inputDescription">Description</label>
                        <textarea name="inputDescription" id="inputDescription"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mpi-check-cont">
                        <label for="checkTitle">Technologies</label>
                        <div class="mpi-check">
                            <div class="check-left">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="checkHtml" class="check-label">HTML
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkHtml" name="checkHtml"check>
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                </label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="checkNode" class="check-label">Node Js
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkNode" name="checkNode">
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="check-right">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="checkCss" class="check-label">CSS
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkCss" name="checkCss">
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                </label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="checkReact" class="check-label">React Js
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkReact" name="checkReact">
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Upload Image</label>
                        <div class="mpi-image">
                            <label for="inputImage">
                    <div class="mpi-choose">Choose</div>
                    <div class="mpi-attach"><i class="fa-solid fa-paperclip"></i></div>
                    </label>
                            <input type="file" id="inputImage" hidden />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mpi-submit">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--xFormx-->

        <!--My Project-->

        <div class="mp-container">
            <div class="mp-title">
                <p>MY PROJECT</p>
            </div>
            <div id="contents" class="mp-card-container">
                <div class="mp-card">
                    <!--MPC = My Project Card-->
                    <div class="mpc-img">
                        <img src="assets/DWB.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mpc-title">
                        <a href="blog-detail.html">
                            <p>Dumbways Bootcamp 2022</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mpc-duration">
                        <small>Durasi: 3 Bulan</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mpc-content">
                        content
                    </div>
                    <div class="mpc-icons">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-html5"></i>
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-css3-alt"></i>
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-node-js"></i>
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-react"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mpc-mod">
                        <button>Edit</button>
                        <button>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--xMy Projectx-->
    </div>
    <script src="js/blog.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here's the blog detail page that will show all of the input value that I submit:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blog detail</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-left">
            <a href="/"><img src="assets/logo.png" alt=""></a>

            <ol>
                <li>
                    <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="myproject.html">My Project</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-right">
            <a href="">Contact me</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--xNAVBARx-->

    <!--Blog Detail-->
    <div id="blog-detail">
        <!--BD = Blog Detail-->
        <div class="bd-title">
            <p>Blog Title</p>
        </div>
        <!--IDC = Image, Duration, Categories-->
        <div class="bd-idc">
            <div class="idc-left">
                <img src="assets/DWB.png" alt="Blog Image">
            </div>
            <div class="idc-right">
                <p>Duration</p>
                <div class="bd-duration">
                    <div style="padding-left: 2px;">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-days"></i>
                        <p>10 May 2022 - 10 Jul 2022</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-clock"></i>
                        <p>3 Month</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bd-tech">
                    <p>Technologies</p>
                    <div class="tech-body">
                        <div class="tech-html">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-html5"></i>
                            <p>HTML</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tech-css">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-css3-alt"></i>
                            <p>CSS</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tech-node">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-node-js"></i>
                            <p>nodeJs</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tech-react">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-react"></i>
                            <p>reactJs</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bd-content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit libero sapiente, minus atque a nesciunt ipsum? Illum sapiente odio provident maxime aut nihil voluptatem officia voluptatibus vel! Necessitatibus, ipsam esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit libero sapiente, minus atque a nesciunt ipsum? Illum sapiente odio provident maxime aut nihil voluptatem officia voluptatibus vel! Necessitatibus, ipsam esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. Suscipit libero sapiente, minus atque a nesciunt ipsum? Illum sapiente odio provident maxime aut nihil voluptatem officia voluptatibus vel! Necessitatibus, ipsam esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                elit. Suscipit libero sapiente, minus atque a nesciunt ipsum? Illum sapiente odio provident maxime aut nihil voluptatem officia voluptatibus vel! Necessitatibus, ipsam esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit
                libero sapiente, minus atque a nesciunt ipsum? Illum sapiente odio provident maxime aut nihil voluptatem officia voluptatibus vel! Necessitatibus, ipsam esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit libero sapiente,
                minus atque a nesciunt ipsum? Illum sapiente odio provident maxime aut nihil voluptatem officia voluptatibus vel! Necessitatibus, ipsam esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit libero sapiente, minus atque
                a nesciunt ipsum? Illum sapiente odio provident maxime aut nihil voluptatem officia voluptatibus vel! Necessitatibus, ipsam esse.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--xBlog Detailx-->
    <script src="js/blog-detail.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I store all the value from input in localStorage with the key name `${blogs[i].title}` in the card title anchor which came from the title input form, how can I access the key name with `localStorage.getItem` for the specific title that I input?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using node js?

Comment: Not yet, I'm learning javascript for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a link to navigate in each blog item:

```
<a href="blog-detail.html" onclick="renderBlog(event)" id='${blogs[i].title} action="blog-detail.html"'>
    <p>${blogs[i].title}</p>
</a>
```

`onclick` run your `renderBlog` function and also navigate to blog-detail.html. You can run the function and avoid the navigation executing `event.preventDefault()`. It's makes sense if you show list of blogs and selected blog in same page, which isn't the case.

So, you need do the navigation. An option to indicate in the page the item to render is add a parameter in the Url. Sonmething like:

```
<a href="blog-detail.html?${blogs[i].title}" action="blog-detail.html"'>
    <p>${blogs[i].title}</p>
</a>
```

And when you load your blog-detail.html, use `window.location.search` (removing the `?` at position 0) to get the title and, with the title, you can access and use your data from storage.

Comment: Where do I use the window.location.search? I use it in `const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(window.location.search.substring(1)))` but the value is null

Comment: Ok I get it now it's null because I use space for the blog name example: `Blog title` the key name would be Blog Title but when I use `window.location.search.substring(1)` it will show `Blog%20Title`. Now that I can get the value but I still can't show it, it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined` when I use `data[i].title`

Comment: Use decodeURIComponent() with the location search.